# W3C validation does not apply for AMP pages, any reason?

Tags: html, amp-html, w3c-validation

None of AMP page would be pass by W3C validation, why so?  As we know that W3C is standard community to validate any page on internet as its developed by taking care HTML code. But when we checked any AMP page and try to pass it from W3C validation then we always get failed response.

Comment: w3c validation for what standard? Also, why do you think AMP pages should respect any standard at all? This is what's called a de facto standard.

Comment: Also, neither chrome nor firefox strictly follow the w3c standards. See also [whatwg](https://whatwg.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Google didn't design AMP to conform to the HTML standard, and either:

- Nobody has written a patch to the Validation Service / Nu Validator to add AMP support *or*
- Somebody has, but there's no desire to merge it

Answer (score 1):

Although the W3C is the official organization for maintaining the standards for HTML (currently HTML 5), it doesn't mean that the browsers support only for the W3C recommended valid HTML codes. Google introduces its latest technology as AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) to ensure the ease of loading the web pages on the mobile screens. Google has changed its searching algorithm that is applicable on the requests/ queries sent through the mobile devices. As a further explanation, it is true and 100% acceptable that every web page is not suitable to load on a mobile screen as it has some sort of specific limitations such as the screen sizes, pixel density and memory capacities of mobile phones.

Therefore, Google gives the priority for the pages which are specifically designed to reach the visitors who prefer to visit the websites from their mobile devices.

In the past, companies (specially Microsoft) which develop web browsers (Internet Explorer), continued the development of their products (browsers) according to their own standards until all of them come to a common general set of standards published by the W3C. Likewise, at present AMP is expected by Google in their ranking algorithms. But later it will be absorbed by other search engines too.

As a best practice, for now, I recommend to fully convert all the general web pages that targets Mobile visitors (accessing the WWW via mobile devices) to AMP. Specially the mobile websites which typically starts their web address from "m." like https://m.example.com

If the AMP project gets success, W3C will update its validation rules to allow the AMP tags and codes as well.